# Should the back-end perform conformity checks before a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

#### Context

By conformity check I mean eliminating queries that definitely are going to return nothing.

For example:

- Consider table `boxes`, where one of the available columns is `color CHAR(6)`;
- A user sends this string `'abcdefg'` to be queried against column `color` through his interaction with the front-end;
- Then, the back-end would execute a query similar to `SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE color = ?`, using the same string mentioned above;

At least in my PostgreSQL installation I can execute this query, even knowing it's never going to return anything (the length of `'abcdefg'` is 7).

Currently, both the front-end and the back-end perform conformity checks prior to accessing data from our DB (to avoid unnecessary calls).

As a matter of fact, the front-end is designed to forbid users from requesting invalid queries. But supposing that these checks didn't take place, especially at the back-end, how significant would that be to an application?

#### Question

How does PostgreSQL treats these queries, does it have any type of algorithm that instantly returns nothing if such a query is executed? Or would it be better to not call the DB and just send to the user something like `not found` or `invalid request`?

#### Further Context

We already sanitize all input acquired from our front-end interfaces, so this is not a question about the possible benefits/downsides regarding the safety gained after the execution of these checks.

The language used at our back-end is Go, which I believe to have no issues at performing these checks regularly (i.e. on most HTTP requests).

PS.: I know you can cast hexadecimal to ints in PostgreSQL, this is just a hypothetical problem which I used to ease the comprehension of the problem (I hope it did).

Comment: [Don't use the char data type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: "how significant would that be to an application?" -- Only you can answer this, by applying actual data to the question. Observe the application in production.

Comment: General advice: It depends on why you're doing these checks. If it's just for performance, then remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil. If it's for security, then you should probably have security checks at multiple levels of the application. If it's for something else, you'll need to consider the pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, like I said, this is a hypothetical problem (based on a real world case), on our applications we don't use the char data type--but thanks for pointing it out, it might help someone reading this =)

BTW, I wish I could upvote twice the 'premature optimization is the root of all evil', made me think about some things going on here. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would perform such checks either in the frontend or in the backend, wherever it is most convenient, but not in both. The second line of defense is the database, and two is enough.

It is a good thing to find incorrect data in the application, but don't go overboard: if you hard-code something like a maximal string length in both the database and the application, you'll have to modify that limit in two places whenever you do, and code redundancy is a bad thing.

What is still sane depends a lot on taste and opinion: I think it is fine to check length limits in the application rather than relying on errors from the database, but I think it is questionable to burden the application with complicated logic that guesses at the results of SQL statements.

What is important is to model all your important consistency checks in the database, then nothing much can go wrong as long as you catch and gracefully handle database errors. Everything beyond that can be considered performance tuning and should only be done if it offers a demonstrable benefit.

Comment: `I would perform such checks either in the frontend or in the backend`. It is secure, or it is not. If OP does this for security reasons, this must be done everywhere, or not at all. I m not convinced re inventing wheel, like op explained, helps in protecting very much. The time spent on working on this tedious checks would be better spent on auditing every other possible holes. Or, IF it is a performance matter, in implementing more rewarding solution to improve the resources consumption.

Comment: So you think that for security, everything has to be checked three times: in the frontend, in the backend and in the database? Hm, ok. I guess it is mostly an opinion based question.

Comment: I think a security measure can not be implemented only halfway through.